Why has rsync created many hidden files that duplicate my real file names?
I have a directory that I periodically rsync to via rsync -rva.
Today I found out that for many files that I have, eg path/to/S00041.jpg, I also have an empty file with the name path/to/._S00041.jpg at the rsync destination.
I imagine they have been created by rsync but I can't be sure.
All of these files have the same timestamp as their corresponding original file so I have no idea when they appeared.
Both source directories and target  are on Mac OS. If this is of any help, I rsync to that directory from different locations and machines (but obviously the directory structure is always the same).
I am very curious if this was done by rsync and why. Also is there an automatic way to "fix" it via rsync?

Likely some macos stuff. See also Why are dot underscore ._ files created, and how can I avoid them?

On MacOS there can be additional information stored in a "Resource Fork" for each file. on a native MacOS filesystem this additional information is (transparently) stored as part of the file itself. However, when files are copied to a non-native filesystem the Resource Fork has to be stored separately. These are the ._* files. Newer applications tend to create Resource Files rather than Resource Forks, so that when such data is exported everything is carried in a single file.
When they are zero length you can safely delete them:
find /path -name '._*' -type f -size 0 -delete

Although you could choose to have rsync skip them, you cannot skip them conditionally, i.e. only when they are zero length.
References:

Why are dot underscore ._ files created, and how can I avoid them?
Macintosh File Forks
Metadata, the Mac, and you


If the files are then restored, copied back to a Mac native file system, will the two files be correctly "combined" (or whatever the right term may be) and the resource fork stored as part of the file again? Is there any point in keeping even  the non empty files?

I believe so, @terdon, based on the suggested cross-reference, but I don't know enough about what can be stored in a Resource Fork to be in a position to test. I'll update the answer if I can confirm this later
